# Implications of asking my employer if it is ok to carry out private work in my own time?

Tags: human-resources

I have been offered some occasional consultancy work outside of my current employment. There is no overlap in the what I am being asked to do and my role, so there is no potential conflict of interest from that point of view.

I am conscious that I don't want any work I do outside of work to impact on my employed work, in terms of work life balance and having enough down time, and I feel that I can manage this.

But could asking my company to do work outside of my current job be thought of as showing a lack of commitment, or interest, will it impact on the way I am thought of?

To be clear, I would not consider doing this work without being transparent, and letting the HR department know.

I am in middle management and on a career path that is going up. I am considering this work as it interests me, and I enjoy it, and to be honest I would welcome some additional income.

Comment: Did you signed a non-disclosure or non-competence agreement? If you did then definitely ask HR or your boss about this. If you did not or this is not the case, I don't see why having a second job is being non transparent.

Answer (score 3):

Disclose it as it could be viewed as a conflict of interest and state in your disclosure the boundaries which ensure the company gets your full support and the side job is literally that, on the side out of the way of the company work.

Follow your companies disclosure policies of whether that is written or just a verbal notification.  If you literally have no disclosure requirements as part of your employment then it's none of their business and you only need to let them know if you have to be absent from work or if it interferes with your current employment obligations.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I agree absolutely, only my question really is what are the 'implications' of considering taking on external work to my standing within the company, rather than how I should go about it.

Comment: @Jessie The ramification really depends on the company, so long as you make sure to communicate in a way that assures them that they won't have any conflict with your current employment it should be fine.  If they are hostile they could fire you or force you to not work external to their company.  Usually they will work with you so long as they still get you as an employee in the way you were before.  We can't fully answer what it will be without knowing the specific individuals involved in calling the shots.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you need to tell the company depends on your relationship to them. If you are salaried, you very likely do have to tell them (or at least will want to) because whether or not you're working for them in what you would call private time is a hazy legal area (and something we can't really handle here).

On the other hand, if you're hourly you may have more flexibility because in that case, your work for your employer is very defined and they'd have a hard time claiming that your off-hours work is theirs.  I'm a contractor and I wouldn't tell my employer if I was doing freelance. But I also wouldn't work for a competitor.

Your case sounds like you're most certainly salaried so I would start with a generic, hypothetical question to HR about what the official company policy is about working in your private time, prior to actually doing it.  That's at least where you need to start and your actions after that depend a lot on what they say as well as who your prospective client is.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I agree absolutely, only my question really is what are the 'implications' of considering taking on external work to my standing within the company, rather than how I should go about it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the people who can answer that are those in your company, not just HR but perhaps people that have been there for a long, long time.